# Add css class ID to largest and smallest number a custom field in wp_query

Tags: php, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I have a `wp_query` for get a ACF number field. I want to add a css class ID to the **largest and smallest number** in the loop.

```php
<ul>
  <?php
  $editor = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'posts_per_page'=>4,
    )
  );
      
  if( $editor->have_posts() ) {
    while( $editor->have_posts() ) {
      $editor->the_post(); ?>
      <li class="number">
        <?php the_field('number_field'); ?>
      </li>
    <?php 
    }
  } ?>
</ul>
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="number largest">100</li>
  <li class="number">45</li>
  <li class="number smallest">2</li>
  <li class="number">38</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And you don't want to sort the results? Is this just a single page of results or can there be multiple pages? What happens if there are duplicate values - put the classes on all 2s, all 100s?

Comment: Are you only interested in the one meta value from the posts? It might be a bit wasteful to read in the whole posts for that, although that's probably simpler than writing SQL just to fetch the number_field.

Comment: It is on one page. I wrote an example of the desired output in the question. I just want the largest class to be added to the larger number to make it green and the smallest class to be added to the smaller number to make it red.

Comment: @Rup  This is only for 4 posts on the car comparison page.

Comment: @Rup there's no reason to write an SQL query here and it might be less performant to do so, especially if an object cache is present

Comment: @omidchahardoli to do this you'd need to know before the loop which post is the largest and which is the smallest, which requires at least 2 variables to hold the largest/smallest, and a second loop before the first to check each post and set them

Comment: @omidchahardoli Are you opposed to a JavaScript solution? This should be possible using JS to scan all the `.number` elements, find the one with the largest number using `.innerHTML()` and then `.addClass('largest')` to that element.